# Possible network issue when all hops lose packets?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I began looking into my networking issues after experiencing random high latency while gaming and also audio drops while in GoToMeeting.

I ran PingPlotter ([results here](https://share.pingplotter.com/77sCHucbj8d)).

The results...I have no idea how to interpret. I would have expected some part in the process to stand out - but it appears like every single hop is losing packets. What are the possible network issues when every hop is latent and losing packets?

Comment: The delta between minimal and average ping time is approximately equal for all hops. This means the problem is located on your station, on the first hop router, or between them (for example, there exist self-hiding node or interface convertor).

Comment: @Akina I've had two different stations experience this issue and so, am inclined to think the problem exists elsewhere. Possibly the router, then? I've never had a router go out on me...is intermittent latency and packet drop a common symptom? (Router is only ~a few years old [Netgear R7800] so it surprises me that the issue may lie here)